# How do I identify the version of Bootstrap?

Tags: bootstrap-theme

There is a general solution on [How do I identify the Bootstrap version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15335537/how-do-i-identify-the-bootstrap-version) but I found it's not useful for Drupal, as I couldn't find the `bootstrap.css` file.

I think I found a bug in it. I want to compare the Bootstrap version against the current one and see if it was already fixed.

How can I check the Bootstrap library version inside a Bootstrap theme?

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed **bootstrap** and enabled it in your themes, you can find the settings in **yoursite.com/admin/appearance/settings/bootstrap**.

If you are using CDN, in Bootstrap **Settings -> advance ->BootstrapCDN version** and the available version in the drop down; or you can go to http://bootstrapcdn.com/ and find the CDN url of the library available in that.

When you use CDN, you can view your CSS or JavaScript file from the CDN server directly.

Answer (score 0):

If no CDN is used, it means the bootstrap.css file is served from your server.

So you can look in your theme's folder possible locations.

- THEMENAME/includes/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css
- THEMENAME/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css

If CSS compression is not enabled on *Configuration > development > performance > Aggregate CSS files*, you can just right click on a page and view the page source to search for *bootstrap.css*, open the file (usually clicking on it). The first few lines will give you version number.  You can probably inspect the *bootstrap.js* file included to get the used version.

If compression is enabled, you might be able to find the version from the corresponding *bootstrap.js* file. Right click and view the page source. At the bottom of the file, you will see the .js file that includes ALL the needed .js files.

```
<script src="/sites/default/files/js/js_bl7kzDdD0bZPEYqsSIW0zHWL86ZfVbExhnLkjlCOMUM.js"></script>
```

Open it (clicking on it) and search for *bootstrap*.